# How to solve a general form of a homework question:

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

First of all the original question is from Halliday Fundamentals of Physics book.

[image]

Figure 2-24 shows a general situation in which a stream of people attempt to escape through an exit door that turns out to be locked. The people move toward the door at speed vs = 3.50 m/s, are each d = 0.25 m in depth, and are separated
by L = 1.75 m. The arrangement in Fig. 2-24 occurs at time t = 0.

(a) At what average rate does the layer of people at the door increase?

(b) At what time does the layer’s depth reach 5.0 m?

My question is: **How to solve a more general form of this problem?** I can only complete(?) part of the problem:

Assuming **n** people waiting to be piled up, with **n** uniform gaps with a uniform **L** length between them originally, with **d** being the uniform thickness of each person. They all move at a constant speed **v**. We need to find the average rate of piling up, and then answer the question of “After how long will the line reaches **X** length?” (n ∈ N*; {L; d; v; X} ∈ R)

Here is what I have:

A/ When **L|d**. This is also the case that the original question falls into:

As people pile up, there can be less distance between person k and k+1 (k is a person who has just piled into the line), particularly the distance shrinks at a fraction of d.

Let's assume: L = md (m $\in$ N*) We observe that after every m people is stacked, the distance that m+1 must travel to stack up with m (and the rest of the line) is reset to L and the time traveled is reset to t = $\frac{L}{v}$. The sum of time taken to stack each m person (from start of this cycle) is:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} \frac{L - nd}{v} = \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} \left(t -\frac{nd}{v}\right) = \frac{m}{2}\left[2t + (m-1)\left(\frac{-d}{v}\right)\right]$$

For the average rate, we assume ∞ cycles of "m-people stacking", so the average rate that the line increases is:

$$\frac{L}{\frac{m}{2}\left[2t + (m-1)\left(\frac{-d}{v}\right)\right]}$$

Plugging numbers in I have:

$$\frac{1.75}{\frac{7}{2}\left[2 × \frac{1.75}{3.50} + (6)×\left(\frac{-0.25}{3.50}\right)\right]} = 0.875 (m/s)$$

To answer how long the total line reaches 5.0m, notice that:

$$5.0 m = (L) × 2 + 1.50 = 1.75 × 2 + 1.5 m$$

Thus that would be:

$$2s × 2 + \frac{6}{2}\left[2 × \frac{1.75}{3.50} + (5)×\left(\frac{-0.25}{3.50}\right)\right] = 5.93 (s)$$

I have no clue how to resolve the case where **L∤d**.

Please let me know if I need to clarify more. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please try not to post your question and solution as images, but use MathJax instead. What exactly are you asking for, let us know what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a simple problem after you notice the recursion in it. It will take the first person $L/v$ seconds to reach the door. After that, the situation is exactly the same as at $t=0$, but with the "door" shifted over by the thickness of the person $d$. The next person will also take $L/v$ seconds to reach the first person, and then be added to the pile, essentially becoming the new door, and so on.

The question at which *average* rate the layer of people increases is a bit ill-formed. The thickness of the pile over time has a staircase shape, because it can only increase by the thickness of a person at a time. Therefore the average will fluctuate depending on how long ago the last person was added to the pile. For $t\rightarrow\infty$, this will match the average rate of change up to exactly the point in time where a person was added (the maximum average rate).

To calculate this, we simply notice that at $t=L/v$ the layer has thickness $d$, so the rate of change is $X/T = d/t = vd/L$. For the numbers given in the original problem, that means $X/T = \frac{3.5 \cdot 0.25}{1.75} = 0.5\,\text{m/s}$.

If $d$ does not divide $X$, we first need to figure out the number of people required to reach $X$. Since there are no fractions of people, we must round the number up (and thus implicitly change the question we are answering to *after how long does the line **equal or exceed** $X$*). The number of people is simply $N = \left\lceil\frac{X}{d}\right\rceil$. Each person takes $t=L/v$ seconds to be added to the pile, so the total time is $T = Nt = \frac{L}{v}\left\lceil\frac{X}{d}\right\rceil$.

Comment: Sorry I did not phrase my answer clearly. My issue with your answer is that the 1st person does travel L length to reach the endpoint (which was the door). However, the 2nd person only has to travel L - d. The 3rd is only L -2d. This continues until the 8th person in which case the distance is reset to L again.

Comment: The separation $L$ is clearly between people, so the front of the first person is a distance $L$ from the door, the front of the second person is $L$ from the back of the first person. Look at the figure again, the end points of the arrows labelled $L$ are not touching, they are separated by exactly $d$.

Comment: I hope this makes sense: So consider 1st and 2nd person. Each has thickness d, and originally separated by the length L. Before movement, 1st person is L (m) away from the door (stopping point), while 2nd person is L (m) away from 1st person. However, after the 1st person has reached the door (and now the 2nd person stands in place of the 1st), the 2nd person only has to move L - d (m) before being stopped exactly at the back of the first person. So the total time to form a line of two people is (L/v) + [(L-d)/v]

Comment: No, at the moment the first person hits the door, the second person is $L+d$ away from the door, and $L$ away from the back of the second person. So it is not exactly where the first person was initially, but $d$ further back. The figure clearly shows the initial position of the front of the second person $2L + d$ away from the door.

Comment: Thank you noah. I have discussed with a friend and figured out my errors. I did not factor individual width into the distance between 2 identical points between person k and k+1 (so instead of L+d I only counted L). Thanks for your patience.